# How do I type any Unicode character into sublime text?

Tags: javascript, unicode

Apparently, [all of these are valid javascript characters](http://codepoints.net/search?gc=Nl) and I want to start using them as var names, but how do I type them into my text editor?

I tried googling a unicode and how to type in unicode characters to no avail.

Comment: I love the no-comment down-vote.

Comment: Another solution is to write a [custom plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290849/replacing-words-with-greek-letters-in-sublimetext) or edit the user key bindings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many of the characters listed in the cited page are in Plane 1, i.e. outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), informally characterized as “16-bit subset of Unicode”. According to the ECMAScript standard, an implementation may support characters outside the BMP, but it need not. In fact, it only requires support to characters that were defined in Unicode version 3.0. Other characters may be used, but they may cause portability issues. In practice, modern JavaScript implementations support full Unicode.

How you type characters depends on your text editor and on other software. There are, for example, utilities that let you enter characters with some special key combinations, either directly inserting them into the current point of insertion or adding them to the clipboard.

As far as I know, the only tool that lets you type any Unicode character is my [full Unicode input utility](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fui.html8). Your editor might have a more integrated tool, but most text editors are rather primitive in Unicode input. Check out Alan Wood’s page [Unicode and Multilingual Editors and Word Processors](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/utilities_editors.html).

Comment: Thanks for all the info, great!!